# How to JOIN tables to SELECT articles with multiple tags?

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have a standard article, tags, and tag_map tables. I `SELECT` authors by a single tag as

```
SELECT author_id, COUNT(*) AS author_articles FROM articles a 
JOIN tag_map b ON a.article_id=b.article_id
JOIN tags c ON b.tag_id=c.tag_id AND c.tag='tag1'
JOIN author_map d ON a.article_id=d.article_id
JOIN authors e ON d.author_id=e.author_id
GROUP BY e.author_id
```

but how I can `SELECT` articles having two or multiple tags?

Comment: You want articles havig more than one tag `COUNT(tag) > 1` or having specific tags  article have `{tag1, tag2, tag3}` ?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query - TBH, at 4K, I kind of expect a bit better.

Comment: I want to find authors of the articles having tag1 and tag2.

Comment: @Strawberry If you see his rep came from php / javascript

Comment: you should use an c.tag IN ( 'tag1', 'tag2') istead  of =

Comment: @scaisEdge That is very simplistic ... and depend if you can have double `tag1` in the query

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  correct this is a comment  not an answer .. but the comment are for this  (too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of simple ways.

Join but where the tag is one of the ones required. Count the DISTINCT articles (as otherwise the count will be doubled), but check that the article has 2 tags using a HAVING clause.

```
SELECT author_id, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT a.article_id) AS author_articles 
FROM articles a 
JOIN tag_map b ON a.article_id=b.article_id
JOIN tags c ON b.tag_id = c.tag_id AND c.tag IN ('tag1', 'tag2')
JOIN author_map d ON a.article_id=d.article_id
JOIN authors e ON d.author_id=e.author_id
GROUP BY e.author_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.tag_id) = 2
```

Or you could just do an extra join.

```
SELECT author_id, 
        COUNT(*) AS author_articles 
FROM articles a 
JOIN tag_map b ON a.article_id=b.article_id
JOIN tags c1 ON b.tag_id = c1.tag_id AND c1.tag = 'tag1'
JOIN tags c2 ON b.tag_id = c2.tag_id AND c2.tag = 'tag2'
JOIN author_map d ON a.article_id=d.article_id
JOIN authors e ON d.author_id=e.author_id
GROUP BY e.author_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need use conditional `Count` in your `HAVING` clause.
Try this:

```
SELECT author_id, COUNT(*) AS author_articles FROM articles a 
  JOIN tag_map b ON a.article_id=b.article_id
  JOIN tags c ON b.tag_id=c.tag_id
  JOIN author_map d ON a.article_id=d.article_id
  JOIN authors e ON d.author_id=e.author_id
GROUP BY e.author_id
HAVING COUNT(c.tag_id)>1
```

Answer (score 1):

use conditional `count()` in your `having`

if you can have duplicated tags you use

```
 HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN c.tag ='tag1' THEN 1 END) >= 1
    AND COUNT(CASE WHEN c.tag ='tag2' THEN 1 END) >= 1
```

if tags are unique you can simplify to

```
 HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN c.tag IN ('tag1', 'tag2') THEN 1 END) = 2
```